# numba parallelize meshgrid

Tags: python, numba, cartesian-product

I am looking for a way to rewrite the code below so that numba can use it. Currently, running the code provides the error `Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.meshgrid' or unsupported use of the function.`. Essentially, I am calculating the 3-ary catesian product (e.g. [0...13] x [0..13] x [0..13]).

```py
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def sequences_of_length(repeat, n_values):
    a = list(range(0, n_values))
    c = [a] * repeat
    x = np.array(np.meshgrid(*c), dtype=np.int16).T.reshape(-1, repeat)
    return x
```

For example `sequences_of_length(3, 13)` should output:

```
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0]
 [ 0  2  0]
 ...
 [12 10 12]
 [12 11 12]
 [12 12 12]]
(2197, 3)
```

(where 2197 = 13^3)

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today and I had to find out that unfortunately mgrid is not one of those functions which `numba` supports. [Here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html) you can see the supported methods and functions that `numba` supports. But `vstack()` is supported and I assume that the next step of your mgrid could be the `vstack`?